# How can I reference the result of one command in the next command in linux?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line-interface, vi

I am fairly new to using Linux and have a simple question that I have not been able to find.  I would like to issue a command and use the result of that command quickly in the next command.  A simple example of this concept would be this:

I would like to issue this command: `find . -iname "*test*"`
 and suppose it returns the following result: `/filepath/madeup/test_file.txt`

Now, I would like in a new command to run `vi /filepath/madeup/test_file.txt`...
Is there a quick alias that I can use to reference the previous result instead of typing the whole filename that I was just given?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `$()` to substitute the output of a command into another command:

```
vi $(find . -iname "*test*")
```

Comment: Awesome! Simple answer to simple question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is call command substitution more info [Here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html).

Basically you can doing in two ways:

1. `vi $(find . -iname "*test*")`
2. vi `find . -iname "*test*"`

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
find . -iname '*test*' -exec vi {} \;
```

Replace `\;` with `+` if there are multiple files and you want to open all in a single `vi` instance.